# Jensen's inequality, Probability with Martingales, David Williams.

Tags: probability-theory

In Probability with Martingales by David Williams he states that $E[|c(X)|]< \infty$. But on Wikipedia: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form) they only have the integrability requirement for the random variable, not for the convex function. And in the proof I can't see where it is used where we need this requirement for Jensen's inequality. Do you see if he uses it, or is it not needed in the proof?, and can be omitted from the theorem?

[image]

Comment: If $\mathbb{E}(|c(X)|)=\infty$ then $\mathbb{E}(c(X))$ might not even be defined.

Comment: @carmichael561 I see thank you. But in the second last line in the proof, he gets that $C(X)\ge m(X-E(X))+c(E(X))$. And then he says that he takes expectation. Will not this imply that $C(X)^-$ is bounded by an integrable function, and hence $E(c(X))$ will be well defined, but might be infinity? Or is he not allowed to take expectation in that case?

Comment: Or can he not do the last step unless he knows it is well defined?

Comment: Some people just like expectations to be finite.  More generally, you can say that a random variable $Y$ has a well defined expectation (possibly being $\infty$ or $-\infty$) if either $E[\max[Y,0]] < \infty$ or $E[\min[Y,0]]>-\infty$.  Now if $c(X) \geq m(X-\mu) + c(\mu)$ then $\min[c(X), 0] \geq \min[m(X-\mu) + c(\mu),0]$ and so $E[\min[c(X),0]] \geq E[\min[m(X-\mu) + c(\mu),0]] > -\infty$ (where the last inequality uses $E[|X|]<\infty$).  So indeed $E[c(X)]$ is always defined (possibly being $\infty$).  And if $E[c(X)]=\infty$ then Jensen's inequality trivially holds.

Comment: The main thing is to ensure $E[X]$ is well defined and finite (in particular, that $E[|X|]<\infty$) since otherwise it does not make sense to evaluate the funtion $c(x)$ at the point $x=E[X]$.  A simple example is when $X$ is exponentially distibuted with mean $E[X]=1$ and $c(x) = e^{x^2}$.  Then $\infty=E[c(X)] \geq c(E[X]) = e$.